# How can erase my IPhone using its home,power, or volume buttons?

Tags: apple-inc, apple-hardware-test

I forgot the password to iPhone and I tried over and over using different buttons.... differently but first i started by holding down the power button and pressing the home button simultaneously. This is what I've heard on other websites.

Comment: if that would be possible what would be the purpose of a password?

Comment: If FindMyiPhone is installed you might be able to remote wipe it.  If you forgot that password too, then try iforgot.apple.com.   If all else fails take it along with proof of ownership to an apple store.

Comment: Also a hardware reset (i.e. holding power and home) will NOT erase the phone.

Comment: Well u can do it on android

Comment: no password, no phone - it's not a toy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to erase all your settings, apps, music, photo's, etc and your iPhone is connected to iCloud, you can kog in to iCloud.con with a mac or pc and then erase the iPhone under the "find my iphone" tab.

When you want to use the iphone again you want habe to put your iPhone in DFU (Device Firmware Update) mode.
You can do so with this tutorial:[DFU tutorial](http://www.iphonehacks.com/put-iphone-in-dfu-mode)